# How To Remove Indents From Code?

Tags: regex, replace, indentation

Lets consider this example of code... Don't look at code, but at indents.

```
        protected function _hashPassword( $password, $salt, $nuts = '' ) {

            if ( $nuts === '' ) {
                $nuts = Kohana::config( 'a11n' )->nuts;
            }


            $password =
                sha1(
                    $password
                    . $salt
                    . $nuts
                );


            return $password;

        }
```

It's taken from much bigger source code. As you can see, it's indented by 2 tabs. I want to somehow remove indent from it without using typing. Somehow.

If I use in-editor build-in 'Replace' function and remove those two tabs like...

[image: 'Replace' function]

I get something like this (not in all cases, but almost)...

```
protected function _hashPassword( $password, $salt, $nuts = '' ) {

    if ( $nuts === '' ) {
$nuts = Kohana::config( 'a11n' )->nuts;
    }


    $password =
sha1(
    $password
    . $salt
    . $nuts
);


    return $password;

}
```

It's because there are more than only two tabs on one line and it replaces all 4 tabs.

**I'm looking for regular expression that's powerful enough to remove indent nicely!** Maybe there are any other solutions? Just don't suggest to write code without indents!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Select the code in your favorite modern editor, and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Wow! This is awesome! Any idea how to do this neat trick for adding 4 spaces in front of code (for StackOverflow format)?

Comment: @daGrevis Settings -> Preferences -> Language Menu/Tab Settings -> Replace by space -> check!

Comment: @daGrevis: pasting your code into the StackOverflow edit box will automatically replace the tabs with 4x spaces.

Comment: @daGrevis, on SO you can select the code and hit `ctrl`+`k` / click the button in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Surely you want to simply replace `^\t\t`, or use whatever character your editor has for the start-of-line anchor if it's not `^` (I have no idea what the capabilities of your particular editor are, only a (pretty good) understanding of how most regular expression engines are driven).

This will only replace two-tab items at the start of each line.

For example, if I were doing this from the command line under Linux,

```
sed 's/^\t\t//g' oldfile.c >newfile.c
```

would do what you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions, replace `^\t\t` with the empty string.
Without using regular expressions, simply replace `\n\t\t` with `\n`.
Also consider using a [source code formatter](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Development_Tools/Source_Code_Formatters/).

Answer (score 1):

The following applies to Notepad++:

1) Set search mode to: Regular expression

2) Find what: `^[\t]+`

3) Replace with:

Edit: This will replace 1 or more tabs from the beginning of every line.

**Alternative method:** select the whole source code and hit `Shift-Tab` multiple times. It will remove the tabs from the beginning of every line, just like the regex above. I hope this helps!

Comment: "Replace with" is an empty string of course, but i guess you know it already. :)

Comment: Err, that will replace _all_ tabs at the beginning of each line. I think OP only wanted the first two.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the OP then. I thought he wants the whole code **without any** indent. I will leave the comment up, until clarification :) You are right of course, thanks.