# is there a shortcut on deleting/adding space of multiple lines in VScode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a way to give multiple line spacings or reduce spacing.

for ex:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    </li>
    <li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

becomes:

```
<ul>
  <li>
  </li>
  <li>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Remove Indents From Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454466/how-to-remove-indents-from-code)

Comment: asking for a space, not indent

Answer (score 27):

You can select all and use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to unindent.

Comment: Yeah I know that but I want to give it 2space instead of indent

Comment: You’ll need to remove the indents and then change the formatting settings to change your indentation from a tab to 2 spaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/29972553

Answer (score 9):

There was a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22637) for that in vscode repo. But it was marked as extension-candidate and closed. So, here is the extension: [Indent One space](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.indent-one-space)

Install it, and select the area which you want to put space/tab at once and press space or tab button accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

you can select multiple line then
-> use `Tab` key for adding space
-> use `Shift` + `Tab` keys for deleting space
from beginning of line in VS code

=>for multiline at same time you can use `Shift` + `Alt` + `Up/Down` arrow key then edit your code or remove/add space.

=>you can edit more then one line at same time in anywhere in code
press and hold `Alt` key then click on lines with mouse. you can edit the text at same time in different lines with different indent.

Comment: wah this really helps

Answer (score 4):

Using VScode you can do it following way:

1. Select all text you want to indent.
2. Press Shift +Alt + i keyboard shortcut.
3. Press Home Button.
4. Add your ident.

Answer (score 1):

For MAC Latex users in OVERLEAF I just found that with fn+tab you can add indentations to all rows marked and with shift+tab you can erase back indentations

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change these several lines, maybe find & replace could help you. find tabs and replace them with two spaces. Don't forget to check "find in selection" or Alt+L.

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode the easiest way to add line space by this 2 steps.

1. Add cursors to the line ends by using Shift + Alt + I short cut
2. Press Enter Key.

   Useful when you are writing Github Readme.md or other Markdowns...

   Before: (You will see 3 file names as single sentence)

   Beginning Git and GitHub A Comprehensive Guide to Version Control.pdf
   Beginning XSLT and XPath.pdf
   Business Intelligence Data Mining.pdf

   After:

   Beginning Git and GitHub A Comprehensive Guide to Version Control.pdf

   Beginning XSLT and XPath.pdf

   Business Intelligence Data Mining.pdf